# Auto assign term to node from term field from user

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 9, workflows

I have a term field called "Organization" on both Content and User entities.

On the Content entity, the field for Organization is hidden.

For the user, they select a value for Organization.

I'd like to automatically assign a value on a Node to be equal to the value of Organization in the User entity (if available, other leave empty).

There seems to be a number of ways to do this:

- Rules, ECA, and other workflow tools
- Context ecosystem of modules
- Prepopulate modules

Constraints include: speed: cannot have node saving slow down due to workflow.

I'm hoping someone has experience implementing such a feature and would kindly shed some light to their approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can easily create a custom module with the following

use hook_entity_presave ...

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/9.4.x

your code would look something like this...

```
 use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

 function YOURMODULE_node_presave(NodeInterface $node) {
   switch ($node->getType()) {
     case "your_content_type":
       
       // Get the current user or //$node->getOwnerId();
       $user = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
       // Probably check if is set ect.. 
       $user_org = $user->field_organization->target_id; 
       $node->set('field_organization', $user_org);
     break;
   }
  }
```

This should not slow saving down too much at all - as making con jobs or adding stuff to the a queue worker to do later would be silly in this case as needing it on a node.